# Excel VBA Dynamic Named Ranges: How to check if range is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an excel sub that will populate an array from entries in a Named Range. The code I have for the range is:

```
=OFFSET(Home!$B$5,1,0,COUNTA(Home!$B:$B)-1,1)
```

I'm trying to write a vba script which will check to see if the Named Range is populated before calling a function, but can't see to get anything to work. Trying:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("NamedRange")
```

returns a 1004 error. And trying:

```
If (IsError(ActiveSheet.Names("NamedRange")) Then
```

returns the same error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Examine **Range.Address**

Comment: Check the scope of the named range. Is it worksheet or workbook?

Comment: Workbook for the scope Cool Blue. Range.Address doesn't seem to return anything either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range        
    Set rng = [NamedRange]        
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "Range is blank"
End Sub
```

In VBA, you can reference the Excel’s range object using the Range property. This can be made shorter using square brackets ([ ]). For example if you’re making reference to cell A1, use "[A1]". The fully qualified reference for cell A1 in Sheet1 of Book1.xlsm will be Application.Workbooks(“Book1.xlsm”).Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1]

Comment: Aha, thanks Siddharth. Using Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA returns a value of 1 even though there are no items in the named range. Think I have a problem with the dynamic range itself... I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Loop through the cells in that range and check if it has a value?

Comment: The above example works. I had column headers above each of the named ranges, and the CountA function was picking up the headers as a value, even if the range was blank. Removed the headers and all is good. Thanks

Comment: http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/03/determine_if_a_.html contains interesting hints as well. And yes I know this is a rather old question (and answer).

Comment: @SiddharthRout I've never seen [] in a code before in vba, what does it do ? i have the same issue than Socii but on the line with the brackets i have a `Object required` error

Comment: As you are aware, in VBA, you can reference the Excel’s range object using the Range property. This can be made shorter using square brackets ([ ]). For example if you’re making reference to cell A1, use "[A1]". The fully qualified reference for cell A1 in Sheet1 of Book1.xlsm will be `Application.Workbooks(“Book1.xlsm”).Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1]`