# Run-time error '424' : Object Required checking if dynamic named range is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I used the solution on this question [Excel VBA Dynamic Named Ranges: How to check if range is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293904/excel-vba-dynamic-named-ranges-how-to-check-if-range-is-blank) but it doesn't work for me, i have a `Run-time error'424': Ojbect required` on the `Set rng = [volTarget]` line.

Here is the code, i've changed the name in the [] and it works with a non-empty dynamic named range.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = [volTarget]
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "Range is blank"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you defined a named range `volTarget`?

Comment: Yes like this `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$5;0;0;1;COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$5:$AZ$5))` and it works when it's not empty

Comment: Are you using a non-English version of Excel (judging by the `;`s you are)? You have to use localized formulas when defining named ranges, so you need to translate the `OFFSET` and `COUNTA`.

Comment: it's an english version and the formula works well

Comment: The code you show for defining `volTarget` is either incomplete or incorrect. Is `volTarget` at the left of the `=` ? If, so then that's a *variable* in your code, not a NamedRange in the Excel workbook. Test selecting the range (as a user) and assigning the name by typing in the "Name Box" (left of the formular bar). Then test the code again.

Comment: @CindyMeister that's the code i put in excel in the `Name Manager` window in the `Refers to` bar at the bottom

Comment: FWIW I did a test with your code and it works fine for me, whether the range contains values or is blank. I only the 424 error when the range name is misspelled (and then it doesn't matter whether there's content, of course). If you're deleting the cells to remove the content instead of clearing them that could be removing the named range? I see that the answer you marked feels the range is missing, as well...

Comment: When i put content in at least one cell, it works so it means that's not misspelled i guess. What do you mean by "deleting the cells" ? Delete the row ? I just clear the cell with "Delete" but the range is still in the `Name Manager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no range named as `volTarget`, VBA throws #NAME error when you try to evaluate it like this `[volTarget]`.

---

In your code, you need to handle the scenario when the named range is missing.

---

One possible approach can be :

```
 Sub Sample()
   Dim rng As Range

   If Not IsError([volTarget]) Then
        Set rng = [volTarget]
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then '=> This is redundant.
            MsgBox "Range is blank"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No such range" '==> This is practically your black range as you are using dynamic named range.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider what happens with that `CLng(CVErr([volTarget]))` when `volTarget` exists and has more than one cell. Also consider what happens when `volTarget` exists, has one cell, and that cell has number 2029 in it.

Comment: thanks @cyboashu for your answer but there is a range named as `volTarget` defined by `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$5;0;0;1;COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$5:$AZ$5))`. The problem is that sometimes it will be empty. I had an error on the set before then i found the same problem (cf question link in my post) but the solution proposed doesn't work for me

Comment: @GSerg, I see your point. IsError is safer :) If the range exists with actual Error Values then that's a different story and needs its own function to differentiate between missing range and/or error values.

Comment: @TmSmth, with dynamic named range all you need to do is check if the range exists. If not then its certainly blank.

Comment: @cyboasho that's what i want to do and it works with `If Not IsError([volTarget]) Then` thanks !